# babel-plugin-react-intl - Plugin doesn't seem to do anything

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, webpack-2, react-intl, babel-plugin-react-intl

I have installed the babel-plugin-react-intl plugin, and added this to my .babelrc file.
I m trying to get the extract messages from my jsx files. My component sources are in ./src

```
{
  "presets": [
    "es2015",
    "react",
    "stage-0"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-object-rest-spread",
    ["transform-runtime", {
      "helpers": false,
      "polyfill": false,
      "regenerator": true,
      "moduleName": "babel-runtime"
    }],
    [
      "react-intl", {
        "messagesDir": "./build/messages",
        "enforceDescriptions": false
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

But nothing happens !
Does anyone perhaps have an idea how to get this plugin working ?

Comment: Are you using react-intl native functions inside your components? react-intl-babel-plugin scans your components and search for its methods/components.

Comment: yes I'm using react-intl functions in my component. For exemple I'm using something like : <FormattedMessage id="username" defaultMessage="Username" />

Comment: this should be enough then. When you save this component that you're using this label, the build/messages folder is not being created in your project?

Comment: yes there is no folder created.

Comment: By the way, you don't need to pass enforceDescriptions: false once it already defaults to false :)

Comment: Ok to remove enforceDescriptions: false. thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169761/discussion-between-periback-and-sami-s).

Comment: did you have any progress? I just installed it in my application with the basic setup and all is working as expected.

Comment: I have try your project, it's working well

Comment: I have compared my conf with yours, it seems OK.. But the output folder isn't created yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I have found the trouble ;-).
It was on my webpack.config.js file, the parameter babelrc was setting to **false** instead of **true** on the module rule part.